# Kubernetes plugin for IntelliJ Idea does not recognize values references

Tags: kubernetes, intellij-idea, kubernetes-helm, intellij-plugin, go-templates

I have an issues with few latest version of Intellij with kubernetes plugin.

I am using helm, so typically my chart looks like below:

```
helm
  templates
    deployment.yaml
    ...
  Chart.yaml
  values.yaml
```

I installed kubernetes plugin, go template as required, added File pattern *.yaml to fily type - helm.

When I am opening deployment.yaml I have there references like

```
{{.Values.strategy.type}}
```

or

```
{{.Values.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge}}
```

However, I see that those references are marked as 'Unknown identifier' and I can not go to that actual value by clicking ctrl+click as it was few versions ago. So it does not recognize the values by references.

I used to see in deployment that Intellij shows me value as a hint instead of pure reference and it was pretty nice to see.

Could someone help me with this? What I am missing.

```
Go Template plugin: 213.5744.190 
Kubernetes plugin: 213.6461.19
IntelliJ: 2021.3.1
```

Comment: Try to temporarily [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins. (except Kubernetes) If the problem remains attach `options/filetypes.xml` from the IDEA system folder (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory)

Comment: Did not helped. 
I am not sure how I could attach this file here...

Comment: You can use https://uploads.jetbrains.com for uploading files. Do not forget to specify the uploadID.

Comment: I think I managed, by populating old filetypes.xml.